# Obtaining insulin in California as a foreign tourist

Tags: health, driving, california

I plan to travel to California and stay more than one month.

I'm an insulin-dependant Diabetic. I am able to bring enough insulin with me to last the entire duration of my visit, but the issue is I'd like to hire a car and drive around the state. This means no access to a fridge on the days I'll be driving (and potentially the nights too, depending on where I stay in between driving days) which means I'll have to store the insulin in a cooling wallet.

Unfortunately in the cooling wallet the maximum lifespan of the insulin is four weeks (in a fridge it's months). Meaning no matter how much I take with me, the most I'm going to be able to use is four weeks' worth, before needing to obtain a 'fresh' supply.

So, **what are my options for obtaining insulin as a foreign tourist in California?** I'm a UK citizen if that's relevant, though I doubt it. I have travel insurance for the US but as far as I know it doesn't cover trips to the doctor for anything non-emergency, if indeed a doctor's prescription will be required.

Can it be done? Or am I basically limited to either staying less than a month, or ditching the driving plan? I really, *really* don't want to give up on this plan :-)

Comment: Have you considered a portable refrigerator that you can plug in to your car? Looks like Walmart sells some for about $50.

Comment: @GregHewgill that is a good shout - will investigate!

Comment: Regardless of fridge, (+1 for that) knowing how to get insulin is needed. Even when you do bring enough for your whole stay, something can go wrong like dropping your last bottle, near the end of your trip. Happened to someone I traveled with, we did not mind the delay to get replacement as it was life saving for her.

Comment: @GregHewgill Beware that the cheap portable refrigerators have a limited temperature range and will not fare well if left in a hot car.

Answer (score 4):

You may be able to obtain a prescription from an Urgent Care facility like [Cal Urgent Care](http://calurgentcare.com/) or an emergency room in the hospital but it may be much simpler to get a portable refrigerator like [Mobicool](http://www.canadiantire.ca/en/automotive/interior-auto-accessories/travel-coolers-warmers.html) or [Koolatron](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Koolatron-8-qt-Traveller-lll-Cooler-12-Volt-P9/202498615?cm_mmc=Shopping%7cBase&gclid=CjwKEAjwiZitBRCy0pb3rIbG9XwSJACmuvvzl4bF3oM9VqFpdxxIBQIwre93oUAc1Z302wBfCEB_qBoCS6rw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds) that you can keep the insulin in and have it plugged in while in the car or with the adapter in any room with an electrical outlet.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to look into the travel fridges - didn't think of that! But just for info, do you know what costs would be involved in getting a prescription from an emergency room or urgent care facility?

Comment: @techpacker Urgent Care facilities costs vary so do Emergency Rooms but insulin at a pharmacy may cost you quite a bit depending on the amount of supply.  Normally a visit to a facility by me will run about $50-$75 a visit for routine stuff.

Comment: @techpacker, no need for thanks, please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: I wouldn't even consider going to an emergency room. Without insurance, going to an ER in the U.S. as a patient will cost you thousands of dollars. An urgent care clinic might work but you'd probably be better off asking your doctor in the UK for a paper prescription to take with you. I'm assuming that your insulin is non-prescription in the UK but he should still be able to write you one. Note also that specific insulins may have different names in different countries.

Comment: @DoxyLover Pharmacy more then likely  not take the foreign script.

Comment: @DoxyLover Insulin actually is prescription-only in the UK and I will take a prescription with me anyway. Do you know of any cases where US pharmacies will take foreign prescriptions?

Comment: @techpacker - actually, after posting my comment, I've done some searching and it appears that Karlson is correct. US pharmacies generally do not accept prescriptions from foreign doctors. I don't have a good answer for you.

Comment: http://www.diabetesforums.com/forum/topic/62461-obtaining-insulin-lantus-glargine-and-novorapid-in-usa/

Comment: @Doxylover as others have said insulin is prescription only in the UK, the advantage is that as diabetics we have a medical exception on prescription charges and so it is zero cost to us. Carrying your script is a good idea,  checking with your Insulin manufacturers support line to make sure that the type of insulin you use is available in the place your are visiting is a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Some forms of insulin are [available Over-The-Counter (OTC), i.e., without a prescription](http://insulinnation.com/treatment/why-is-some-insulin-available-over-the-counter/), in the USA. Also see [this article](http://www.npr.org/sections/health-shots/2015/12/14/459047328/you-can-buy-insulin-without-a-prescription-but-should-you).

Insulin *syringes* are also available OTC, and Walgreens (a major pharmacy chain in the USA) [mentions](https://www.walgreens.com/topic/faq/questionandanswer.jsp?questionTierId=700020&faqId=7700001) that California is one of those states that permit it.

Before relying on OTC insulin, speak with your physician about what kind of insulin you need and make sure you can get that specific type in California. Don't get caught without the medications that you need.